# Python stdin buffering issue when passing input to shell command

Tags: python, input

I'm running the following script with Python 3:

```
import sys, subprocess

line = sys.stdin.readline()
print(f'[p] {line}', end='')
subprocess.run('read one; echo "[s] $one"', shell=True)
line = sys.stdin.readline()
print(f'[p] {line}', end='')
```

If I run this script normally, this happens, as I expected:

```
a
[p] a
b
[s] b
c
[p] c
```

(I've typed three lines, with a single letter on each). However, if I create a text file containing these three lines, and run it using `python3 script.py < file.txt`, I get the following output:

```
[p] a
[s]
[p] b
```

When I expect to get

```
[p] a
[s] b
[p] c
```

I'm fairly sure this is due to an stdin buffering issue. I've tried (to no avail) setting `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`, and running Python with `-u`. Can I disable stdin buffering? Or can I access the contents of the buffer to pass them to my shell command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a buffering issue, and I think this statement from the documentation of the `io` module is relevant:

"TextIOWrapper, which extends it [talking about TextIOBase], is a buffered text interface to a buffered raw stream"

The type of `sys.stdin` is TextIOWrapper, so it seems the buffering can't be got rid of using just `sys.stdin`.

However, it seems you can do this:

```
import io
f = io.FileIO(sys.stdin.fileno())
```

and then do `f.readline()`, independent of whether you specify -u or not.

The question remains whether this is a good idea at all. I think an implementation which relies so critically on exactly how much is buffered is very unreliable.

Comment: You seem to run at least python 3.5. I tried with python 2, and there, -u with your code did make a difference.